# Unable to select "use .Net Standard" when creating a new blank form app in visual studio for mac

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am facing a weird situation when creating a Blank Form App in visual studio for mac. The option of ".Net Standard" is greyed out and I am unable to select it. The only option by default is the "Shared Code". I am using Visual Studio Code version 7.5.2

[image: Blank App Xamarin]

Comment: .netstandard is only a valid selection for class library projects.  Such a project needs to observe the restrictions in .netstandard, UI is heavily non-standard.  The main app needs to target a specific platform.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your first project with this issue? Did you use Xamarin with VS before?
If yes, I suggest you to check the modules you have installed. Be sure you have the ".NET desktop development" (in the section "Windows").

[image]

Comment: No, I have not used Tamarin before with Visual Studio. I think you are talking about Visual Studio in Windows. My issue is about visual studio for mac.